# Trouble with declaring variables in file_put_contents

Tags: php, function

I am having difficulty determining the correct syntax on how to create a new file and put a series of variables and includes in the file.  The plan is to make an index to a directory that knows what directory it is in, ideally I would like the index.php to look like this:

`<?php $projectAccess = "Project Name"; ?>`
`<?php include('meta-data.php'); include('header.php'); include('content.php'); include('footer.php'); ?>`

I having been struggling with this for a little while now with variations of this code (which has gotten me the closest so far):

```
function indexData($projectAccess) {
   $projectString = "<?php $projectAccess = '" . $projectAccess . "'; ?> ";
   $includes = "<php include('meta-data.php'); include('header.php'); include('content.php'); include('footer.php'); ?>";

   return $projectString . $includes;
}

file_put_contents($path3, indexData($w_title));
```

But this returns:

```
<?php Project Name = 'Project Name'; ?> <php include('meta-data.php'); include('header.php'); include('content.php'); include('footer.php'); ?>
```

I want the first PHP statement to be delcaring the variable `$projectAccess` as "Project Name" but it just iterates the string instead of putting the variable there.  I know I am doing something basic wrong, please help!

`$path3` refers to the file that is being created, which is determine earlier in the script and is something I am not having trouble with, only the `indexData()` part is tricky.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess I am looking for a way to escape the variable in the function so that it writes it as is in the new file?  Would `addslashes` help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar sign.

Replace this

```
function indexData($projectAccess) {
   $projectString = "<?php $projectAccess = '" . $projectAccess . "'; ?> ";
   $includes = "<php include('meta-data.php'); include('header.php'); include('content.php'); include('footer.php'); ?>";

   return $projectString . $includes;
}
```

with this

```
function indexData($projectAccess) {
   $projectString = "<?php \$projectAccess = '$projectAccess'; ?> ";
   $includes = "<php include('meta-data.php'); include('header.php'); include('content.php'); include('footer.php'); ?>";
   return $projectString . $includes;
}
```

Also, take a look in the [manual wrt. how PHP treats double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Another thing is that there is an error in the declaration of `$includes` - `<php` should be `<?php`, but the whole this can be rewritten like this for better readability:

```
function indexData($projectAccess) {
    return "
       <?php
           \$projectAccess = '$projectAccess';
           include('meta-data.php');
           include('header.php');
           include('content.php');
           include('footer.php');
       ?>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for the string. PHP doesn't convert variables when they are within single quotes. 
Like this:

```
 
function indexData($projectAccess) {
   $projectString = '<?php $projectAccess = "' . $projectAccess . '"; ?> ';
   $includes = "";

   return $projectString . $includes;
}

file_put_contents($path3, indexData($w_title));
```

Hope this helps.